# How do you run a powershell script from within venv?

Tags: powershell, flask, virtualenv

I'm trying to develop a SPA with PyCharm which uses venv as the virtual environment for my project.

I'm following this tutorial https://auth0.com/blog/using-python-flask-and-angular-to-build-modern-apps-part-1/ but the config is based on a linux system. I'm stuck on the part where I want to run a bootstrap script to run my flask app from the command line.

It seemed reasonable to put this into a PowerShell script, as I'm developing on Windows 10, but I'm unable to run this script from within venv.

The script itself just contains the following:

$env:FLASK_APP = "./src/main.py"

flask run -h 0.0.0.0

Now, within venv I can only launch a PowerShell terminal. I can't actually run this script from within venv directly. If I navigate to the venv folder from within PowerShell my script will be executable but it's obviously not working as flask is only available within venv.

So, please can somebody show me the best practice for running a script from within venv that will run my flask app?

Comment: I know nothing about virtual environments, but can't you run the script via PowerShell's CLI, along the lines of `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File path/to/your/script.ps1`?

Comment: I can certainly run the script via PowerShell as you've described but the contents of the script need to be executed within the virtual environment. Otherwise those commands won't mean anything to PowerShell. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can dot source the pipenv with :

```
cd YourProjectPath
$venv = pipenv --venv
. "$venv\scripts\activate.ps1"
#"rest of your script"
$env:FLASK_APP = "./src/main.py"
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

if you are directly using venv , then:

```
. .\your env name\Scripts\Activate.ps1
#"rest of your script"
$env:FLASK_APP = "./src/main.py"
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: So within my script I should source the Activate script? If I'm directly using venv and have an active environment then why do I need to source this script? Just trying to understand how this actually works. Thanks.

Comment: @hebrodoth yes, you can activate pipenv from the script (This is similar to the  `source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate` that you saw in the tutorial), for venv you don't need to do this but I wrote the snippet in case you wanted something similar for that